# HTML5's window.postmessage not working below IE9 IEs

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain

i have a [very simple demo](http://t0mjane1.webng.com/cpminwan/container.htm) for cross domain communication in iframes using html5's postMessage API. it successfully works for me in all modern browsers and in IE9 as well but not in IE8 or below.

I tried a solution of registring some html5 tags with a custom header but the window.postMessage is still something mysterious for IE8.

Yes i know i can use various ways for cross domain in IE8 like xdr, but for cleanness somebody please comment if window.postMessage can somehow work in IE8 or below.

Comment: Note that your page won't be in standards mode in IE because an advert is getting inserted before your `DOCTYPE`, this will cause several HTML5 features not to work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip robertc i have tested this demo on my local tomcat which is definitely without ads and html5's window.postMessage still doesnt work in IE8.
i uploaded demo on server with some ads unfortunately to show u guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, IE8 does not allow `postMessage` across tabs/windows, only between `iframe` and parent: [reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/Bugs-in-IE8-support-for-HTML5-postMessage-sessionStorage-and-localStorage.aspx). Below IE8 you're out of luck, as IE7 was released in 2006, and HTML5 has been adopted as a working draft by the W3C in 2007.

Comment: there are some hacks for cors below ie9 like polling, proxying and some libraries like easyxdm and modernizer, so should i append their support for browsers <ie9. Comment.

Comment: CORS does not seem supported below IE8 either. If pre-IE9 support is important to you, then by all means you should use a cross-domain comms hack. I don't think modernizr can help you in this, it is mostly feature-detection library, not replacement for missing features.

Comment: Thx lanzz. Yes modernizer isnt aiding that way though other hacks like polling and proxifying does the job for me.